# Visual Studio 2015 XAML Editor Text color

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2015, colors, themes, editor

I am using the `Dark theme` of `Visual studio` and there is one particular color which in my opinion is too weak.

I have tried to change it but couldn't really succeed.

[image: Sample 1_1: Designer]

When you click on an object in the designer, the `XAML editor` will try to mark the code by changing the objects background:

[image: Sample 1_2: Xaml editor]

Now if you pay attention, then the background of `<ComboBox... >` is changed, but the difference is not that much. And I want to change that.

In the next sample the same code is shown with another theme:

[image: Sample 2_1 Xam editor]

In the sample above it is much more clear. And I want to make the same for the Dark theme.

**Does anybody know how to do that ?**

I have tried **`Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Fonts and Colors:`**

[image: Sample 3_1 Options]

There are so many possibilities, and I have clicked on all of them, but couldn't really find the particular color I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In **`Tools >> Options >> Environment >> Fonts and Colors`** you need to select `TextEditor` in the **`Show settings for:`** combo, and the option under **`Display items:`** responsible for that color is called `Inactive Selected Text` (it's the 3rd option from the top in my VS). You can then use the **`Item background:`** color picker to select preferred color. Note though that this will change the background color of inactive selected text in all text editors, not just in the *XAML* editor. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Yes! Thanks exactly what I was looking for.